# React Axios Handle 401

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, axios

how to handle 401 Unauthorized status code with Axios Interceptor. This snippet print error in console but I still get RED error code in console, how to remove it?

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
 response => {
   console.log("Axios Response: ", response);
   return response;
},
error => {
 if (error.response.status === 401) {
  console.log("RESPONSE 401");
  return Promise.reject(error.response);
}
console.log("Axios Response Error: ", error.response);
return Promise.reject(error);
```

}
);

[image]

Comment: *Don't* reject the promise? Catch the rejection in the consumer?

Comment: @jonrsharpe short snippet?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

Comment: @jonrsharpe I catch it but how to consume error

Answer (score 1):

What you see is most probably automatic logging by Chrome and you can't remove it. When I open debugger on StackOverflow's page I see 2 such requests that were blocked by ad blocker:

[image: blocked requests]

You can maybe try removing both `return Promise.reject(error.response);` calls but I don't think this will help any.

Comment: That is what I want, I tried but no success, thank you